# How to run Intl.NumberFormat Javascript in Swift playgrounds?

Tags: javascript, swift, parsing, swift-playground

I'm experimenting with an idea to use `Intl.NumberFormat` from Javascript, specifically the compact variant to shorten numbers down into a more human readable format and I want to run the script in Swift Playgrounds.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Quoting the compact/short format notation:

```
> console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { notation: "compact", compactDisplay: "short" }).format(987654321)); 
// → 988M
```

I've created a Javascript file called jssource.js and included a small function which I've verified works in the Mozilla link I included.

```
// jssource.js
var format = function(number) {
  return (Intl.NumberFormat('en-GB', { notation: "compact" , compactDisplay: "short" }).format(number));
}
```

I've also verified that it works in some browsers.

The problem is, that in Swift Playgrounds it doesn't match the expected behaviour.  100000 returns 100,000 when it should be 100K

I've created a basic swift playgrounds file, added the file to my Resources; then wrote this code to quickly read the JS file and fire the function.

Swift playground code:

```
import Foundation
import JavaScriptCore

class JSContextParser {
    var jsContext: JSContext!

    init() {
        self.jsContext = JSContext()
    }

    func initializeJS() {
        let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"jssource", ofType: "js")

        do {
           // Load its contents to a String variable.
           let jsSourceContents = try String(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

           // Add the Javascript code that currently exists in the jsSourceContents to the Javascript Runtime through the jsContext object.
           self.jsContext.evaluateScript(jsSourceContents)
       }
       catch {
           print(error.localizedDescription)
       }
    }

    func format(number: Double) {
        let testFunction = self.jsContext!.objectForKeyedSubscript("format")
        let result = testFunction?.call(withArguments: [number])
        print (result ?? "N/A")
    }

}

let parser = JSContextParser()
parser.initializeJS()
parser.format(number: 100000)  // Expect 100K, Get: 100,000
```

Other numbers don't seem to display as expected either.  But in the browser and on the Mozilla website it works fine.

I'm not sure why Swift Playground is unable to run the `Intl` code; according to the Mozilla document its a standard built-in object.

What could be causing this issue and how to resolve?

With thanks